# Spring Jackson serialization of a List of Objects doens't work as expected

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have to serialize a list of users.

This is my controller method declaration

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<UserDTO> getUsersData(Authentication authentication) {
      // .... 
      // get users from the service layer as an ArrayList
      List<UserDTO> users = userService.getUsers(authentication.getName());
      return users;
}
```

On the client side I get this JSON:

```
{"ArrayList":[
    {"id":8,"firstName":"User1 FN","lastName":"User1 LN"},
    {"id":9,"firstName":"User2 FN","lastName":"User2 LN"}
]}
```

I would expect to receive:

```
{[
    {"id":8,"firstName":"User1 FN","lastName":"User1 LN"},
    {"id":9,"firstName":"User2 FN","lastName":"User2 LN"}
]}
```

What am I missing here?!

Comment: Seems that you have wrapped the reposnse an within there is an attribute called ArrayList. Can you add more details?

Comment: Actually I have a response which is an ArrayList. The same problem was described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806938/serialize-list-of-objects-to-json-with-jackson-spring-mvc, but for me the solution doesn't work.

Comment: The only difference between issue is the signature of method, You've as return type List<UserDTO> instead in the other there is only List . Do you tried to change it?

Comment: The problem was with the servlet.xml config. I had to declare the schema for MVC. so that I could use mvc:annotation-driven (which was not declared previously)